# How to test ChromeCasting locally without Android TV or ChromeCast device?

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm building a mobile app and trying to implement chromecasting. I want to test whether my sender application is working or not but I don't have a Casting device. Is it possible to test it?

I've set up android tv emulator but it didn't show up. Probably I need additional settings.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24252711/9779791) is asked 7 years ago, but I'm not sure if it's possible in 2021.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will there be Chromecast Receiver Emulator or an alternate app that acts as a receiver for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845596/will-there-be-chromecast-receiver-emulator-or-an-alternate-app-that-acts-as-a-re)